# Update one dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes where B is subset of A. If I change a single value in B, then that change should be updated in another dataframe A also. Dataframes have index of unique ids in column A.
How can I implement this using pandas library?

Suppose,
A dataframe is, 

  `A B C D
0 1 4 6 8
1 2 3 5 7
2 3 2 3 4
3 4 8 9 10
4 5 5 6 7`

B dataframe is,

  `A B C D
0 3 0 3 4
1 5 8 6 7`

Output should be

  `A B C D
0 1 4 6 8
1 2 3 5 7
2 3 0 3 4
3 4 8 9 10
4 5 8 6 7`

Comment: @jezrael updated. I want to update values of specific rows in A which exists in B. That repeated problem updates values from starting index

Comment: Use `B.combine_first(A)`

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Comment: Yes, combine first adds duplicants. Please check edited. Sorry for inconvenience. Column A includes ids. And according to them I want updates.

Comment: Then use `B.set_index('A').combine_first(A.set_index('A'))`

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much.